# How can i get the HTTP respense after using a CAMEL Failover EiP (Load Balancer)?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel, load-balancing, jbossfuse

This the route:

```
<route> 
<from uri="direct:xyz"/> 
<loadBalance> 
    <failover maximumFailoverAttempts="2" roundRobin="false"> 
    <exception>java.net.NoRouteToHostException</exception> </failover> 
    <to uri="http://URi1"/>
    <to uri="http://URi2 "/>
</loadBalance>
```

I use URi2 when connetion with URi 1 cannot be established.
How can i display the response ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to break your current pattern I would recommend using the failover over direct endpoints.  Disclaimer:  I usually work in DSL so syntax might be slightly off.

```
<from uri="direct:xyz">
    <loadBalance> 
        <failover maximumFailoverAttempts="2" roundRobin="false"> 
        <exception>java.net.NoRouteToHostException</exception> </failover> 
       <to uri="direct:primary"/>
       <to uri="direct:secondary"/>
    </loadBalance>
</from>

<from uri="direct:primary">
    <errorHandler id="noErrorHandler" type="NoErrorHandler"/>
    <to uri="http://URi1"/>
    //Response handling
</from>

<from uri="direct:secondary">
    <errorHandler id="noErrorHandler" type="NoErrorHandler"/>
    <to uri="http://URi2"/>
    //Response handling
</from>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply ! in this case URi1 will always receive a request even if it don't work

Comment: If URI1 throws an exception and doesn't find an error handler, the error will propagate back to the failover loadbalancer and go to the second URI.  Unfortunately, Camel doesn't have a "sticky" loadbalancer from what I have seen, but you could always implement your own load balancer or use a network loadbalancer to hide the URI failures from the application.